# What are the differences between running a process with and without a shell?

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

In the [Node.js docs for `child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), I came upon this line:

> Since a shell is not spawned, behaviors such as I/O redirection and file globbing are not supported.

That’s good to know, but the “such as” worries me. **What other behaviors are missing?** What even counts as running without a shell — isn’t `sh`/`cmd.exe` still parsing the command-line input?

Comment: No other behaviors are missing. There are many ways to communicate with a child-process that do not involve initial input from the shell. Ports, shared-memory, IPC (inter-process-communication), etc.. There is no need for a shell in those cases, the parent process simply "forks" off a child-process with whatever communication needed between the two already defined.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like my initial assumption was flawed: neither the Bourne shell (`sh`) nor Windows’s `cmd.exe` parses the command when invoked without a shell — it’s up to the consuming application to do so.

The most significant lost feature is the lack of filename expansion. Unless the called application binary understands UNIX file syntax, you can’t do most relative file path tricks:

- No `../` for a parent directory
- No `./` for the current working directory
- No `~` for the user directory

Other shell syntax characters like redirection operators (`>` for example) and pipes (`|`) are unsupported.

**Basically, if it’s listed as a feature on the shell’s wikipedia page, non-shell execution won’t have it.**

Comment: Note that this answer as presently written is very specific to Windows. On UNIX, the shell is responsible for parsing the string into a command-line argument list, which is passed to the consuming application as an array (as in the `int main(int argc, char**argv)` calling convention). You can't even call a "consuming application" *at all* without generating that array ahead-of-time.

Comment: Also, `.` and `..` are honored by the OS syscalls (like `open()`), so they're fine without a shell (on UNIX; I can't speak to Windows). Only `~` that is not; I'd hardly call that "significant", compared to `>`/`<` and compound-command operators like `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Look at the manual page for the `execve` syscall, which is how a new program is started at the OS level -- you'll see it takes a single C string as the filename of the program to invoke, an array of C strings for the argument list to pass that program, and an array of C strings as the list of arguments to pass. Anything like Node's `child_process` module or Python's `subprocess` module is eventually implementing that interface under-the-hood.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept a better answer if this one is lacking — I'm trying to figure this out as I go along myself.

Comment: Hmm. I could write an authoritative answer for UNIX, but if you want something that's accurate on Windows as well, I'm not in a position to provide it. That said, I'm quite certain we have duplicates for the general question (not specific to node.js, but for the general case, ie. Python's `shell=True` in its subprocess module -- answers that will still apply).